# What is meant by "Selected papers will be published" in conference proceedings?

Tags: publications, mathematics, conference, proceedings

Let assume that a submitted abstract accepted and then presented in a conference. In some conference they say that "selected papers will be published in proceeding". What they mean by term "***Selected***"? What steps are there after presentation of research work?

Comment: Maybe the field you have encountered this in is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What they mean by term "Selected"? What steps are there after presentation of research work?

In my field (machine learning), it means reviewers will be tasked  to select papers they deemed the most interesting (the criteria depend on the venue). Probably true in any field.

> What steps are there after presentation of research work?

The exact steps depends on the venue. But the idea is that reviewer will do some selection based on what is sent to them, typically a paper.

Answer (score 0):

The conference committee, or perhaps just the program committee, will select some of the abstracts/papers. For abstracts they may ask for a full paper to be published in the proceedings. Or, they might just publish the abstracts as submitted, perhaps after some editing.

There could also be a special selection committed organized for this purpose. The committee might include an editor who is part of the conference committee and who has a major voice in which papers are selected.

In some cases the proceedings are published by a major publisher, in others, by the professional association that sponsored the conference.